# ansible string split with set facts

Tags: regex, ansible

Hi I am trying to to achieve something below.

[root@WEBSERVER]# ll /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-* | grep sdd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 25 15:26 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1234567891123455 -> ../../sdd

I want assign "/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1234567891123455" from the above output to a variable.

Ansible:

- name: Capture output
  command: ll /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-* | grep sdd
  register: lsblkoutput

Now I want to querty lsblkoutput and the /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1234567891123455

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried, and what does not Work? Also please give more examples of input and expected output.

Comment: What is 'lsblkoutput'? That's not part of the string.

Comment: Hi, My string is "  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 9 Oct 25 15:26 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1234567891123455 -> ../../sdd" and I've assigned this string to a variable called lsbkoutput.

Comment: Here is my Ansible code:

- name: set the value
  set_fact:
    output_value: "lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Oct 25 09:46 /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-1234567891123455 -> ../../sdd"

- name: select the first word
  set_fact:
    final_output: '{{ output_value.split()[8] }}'

- name: display
  debug:
    msg: " output is {{ final_output }}"

Second part of my code pickups the value I needed by using split()[8], however is there any betterway to pickup the value I need by using some patter rather than hardcoding the 8th value.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge af 'Ansible', but I have created a regex that matches, what you want.
However, since I don't know Ansible, I don't know, if your regex supports this pattern:

```
lrwxrwxrwx[^/]*(.*(?=\s->))
```

The regex matches the Word 'lrwxrwxrwx', followed by zero or more characters, until it reaches a slash `'/`'. Then it matches any characters as long as there's '`.>`', when looking ahead.

The value, you're looking for, is in the captured `Group 1.`

Hope you can use this in Ansible.